# Tensorflow incorrectly loading data: Data normally Channel x Height x Width is being loaded as Height x Width

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, computer-vision, tensorflow2.0

So Ive constructed a DenseNet/Unet like structure for my computer vision problem. But when I feed my images and masks into the model.fit() method, somewhere in the backend Tensorflow removes the channel portion of my input, and thus sends in an incorrectly shaped tesnor to the first convolutional layer.

My Image_list object has shape (# of slices x 1 x 512 x 512). So ideally, the input of each slice should be 1x512x512.

The error is :

```
WARNING:tensorflow:Model was constructed with shape (None, 1, 512, 512) for input Tensor("input_1:0", shape=(None, 1, 512, 512), dtype=float32), but it was called on an input with incompatible shape (None, 512, 512).
```

This leads me to believe that somehow, there is an error with the Input layer??

---

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-a8d0a842563e> in <module>()
      1 #obj= ImageSequence(None, None,1)
----> 2 model.fit(image_list,mask_list, epochs=1 )

10 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py in _method_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs)
    106   def _method_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
    107     if not self._in_multi_worker_mode():  # pylint: disable=protected-access
--> 108       return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
    109 
    110     # Running inside `run_distribute_coordinator` already.

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_batch_size, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing)
   1096                 batch_size=batch_size):
   1097               callbacks.on_train_batch_begin(step)
-> 1098               tmp_logs = train_function(iterator)
   1099               if data_handler.should_sync:
   1100                 context.async_wait()

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwds)
    778       else:
    779         compiler = "nonXla"
--> 780         result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
    781 
    782       new_tracing_count = self._get_tracing_count()

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py in _call(self, *args, **kwds)
    821       # This is the first call of __call__, so we have to initialize.
    822       initializers = []
--> 823       self._initialize(args, kwds, add_initializers_to=initializers)
    824     finally:
    825       # At this point we know that the initialization is complete (or less

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py in _initialize(self, args, kwds, add_initializers_to)
    695     self._concrete_stateful_fn = (
    696         self._stateful_fn._get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected(  # pylint: disable=protected-access
--> 697             *args, **kwds))
    698 
    699     def invalid_creator_scope(*unused_args, **unused_kwds):

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py in _get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected(self, *args, **kwargs)
   2853       args, kwargs = None, None
   2854     with self._lock:
-> 2855       graph_function, _, _ = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
   2856     return graph_function
   2857 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py in _maybe_define_function(self, args, kwargs)
   3211 
   3212       self._function_cache.missed.add(call_context_key)
-> 3213       graph_function = self._create_graph_function(args, kwargs)
   3214       self._function_cache.primary[cache_key] = graph_function
   3215       return graph_function, args, kwargs

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py in _create_graph_function(self, args, kwargs, override_flat_arg_shapes)
   3073             arg_names=arg_names,
   3074             override_flat_arg_shapes=override_flat_arg_shapes,
-> 3075             capture_by_value=self._capture_by_value),
   3076         self._function_attributes,
   3077         function_spec=self.function_spec,

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py in func_graph_from_py_func(name, python_func, args, kwargs, signature, func_graph, autograph, autograph_options, add_control_dependencies, arg_names, op_return_value, collections, capture_by_value, override_flat_arg_shapes)
    984         _, original_func = tf_decorator.unwrap(python_func)
    985 
--> 986       func_outputs = python_func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
    987 
    988       # invariant: `func_outputs` contains only Tensors, CompositeTensors,

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py in wrapped_fn(*args, **kwds)
    598         # __wrapped__ allows AutoGraph to swap in a converted function. We give
    599         # the function a weak reference to itself to avoid a reference cycle.
--> 600         return weak_wrapped_fn().__wrapped__(*args, **kwds)
    601     weak_wrapped_fn = weakref.ref(wrapped_fn)
    602 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    971           except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
    972             if hasattr(e, "ag_error_metadata"):
--> 973               raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
    974             else:
    975               raise

ValueError: in user code:

    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:806 train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:796 step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:1211 run
        return self._extended.call_for_each_replica(fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:2585 call_for_each_replica
        return self._call_for_each_replica(fn, args, kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:2945 _call_for_each_replica
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:789 run_step  **
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:747 train_step
        y_pred = self(x, training=True)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py:985 __call__
        outputs = call_fn(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/functional.py:386 call
        inputs, training=training, mask=mask)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/functional.py:508 _run_internal_graph
        outputs = node.layer(*args, **kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py:976 __call__
        self.name)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/input_spec.py:196 assert_input_compatibility
        str(x.shape.as_list()))

    ValueError: Input 0 of layer conv2d is incompatible with the layer: : expected min_ndim=4, found ndim=3. Full shape received: [None, 512, 512]
```

My code can be found here: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1FwuS2Wa589CvbiqOgAznqqnbKruez9Nj?usp=sharing

Sample Dataset: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1K4zL49pnDQsQDagCgHZko8jbtN-UNfX0?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data generator returns a list of NumPy array, a list of arrays can be interpreted as multiple inputs. Try to put your data in tensor form before calling model .fit() :

```
`image_list = tf.convert_to_tensor(image_list)

mask_list = tf.convert_to_tensor(mask_list)`
```

Comment: It is supposed to be multiple inputs? Its supposed to be slices of an image that Im feeding in for 2D convolutions. Either way, making it a tensor gave me a resource allocation error: `ResourceExhaustedError:  OOM when allocating tensor with shape[32,54,256,256] and type float on /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 by allocator GPU_0_bfc
  [[node functional_7/concatenate_159/concat (defined at <ipython-input-34-a8d0a842563e>:2) ]]`

Comment: OOM , try a fewer batch size .e.g 8

Comment: I have been stuck on this problem for a week and a half, and you have given me the answer. No amount of **thank you's** explains the emotions I am feeling right now!!